# Compiling error with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, compiling, tikz-node

In this TikZ [manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf), beginning of page 76, a simple code is presented. After trying to compile a document with it,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill=red!30,rounded corners]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[red,-o,thick,draw]
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I got this error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/edge from parent fork down' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...in{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down]
```

Maybe some definition is missing? Or what else?

Note that the second example in the same page is successfully compiled instead.

Comment: You should not add the [edge from parent fork down], as the error tells you, just \begin{tikzpicture}

Comment: @HenkMetselaar Of course I had tried, but it doesn't work as well. It gives error with the `right` child curly brackets, which are instead correct.

Comment: That manual is ancient, don't use it. The current version is 3.0.1a. Open a terminal/command prompt on your computer and enter `texdoc tikz`, or go to for example [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for an up to date version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual you refer to is very out of date, but the example is also somewhat incomplete. Two specific libraries are required:

```
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
```

The corresponding code from the current version of the manual (page 121, for version 3.0.1a of `pgf`/TikZ):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[edge from parent fork down, sibling distance=15mm, level distance=15mm,
every node/.style={fill=red!30,rounded corners},
edge from parent/.style={red,-o,thick,draw}]
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```